# Custom JS Callback for allowing only one circle to be shown on hovering in Circle plot in Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, hover, bokeh, glyph

I am new to Bokeh 
I am trying to replicate the line plots shown in https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ using Bokeh.Here is my full code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import requests
import json

from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Title

    def DateFormatter(x):
        s = '01222020'
        global given_date
        given_date = datetime(month=int(s[:2]), day=int(s[2:4]), year=int(s[4:]))
        given_date += timedelta(days=x)
        final = str(given_date.strftime('%m{}%d{}%y').format('/','/'))
        if int(final[0:2])<10 and int(final[3:5])<10:
            final = final[1:]
            final = final[0 : 2 : ] + final[3 : :]
        elif int(final[0:2])<10:
            final = final[1:]
        elif int(final[3:5])<10:
            final = final[0 : 2 : ] + "/" + final[4 : :]
        return final

    def DateFormatterForPlot(x):
        s_plot = '01222020'
        global given_date_plot
        given_date_plot = datetime(month=int(s_plot[:2]), day=int(s_plot[2:4]), year=int(s_plot[4:]))
        given_date_plot += timedelta(days=x-1)
        final_plot1 = str(given_date_plot.strftime('%b %d'))
        if int(final_plot1[4:6])<10:
            final_plot1 = final_plot1[0 : 4 : ] + final_plot1[5 : :]
        return final_plot1

    finallist=[]
    l2 = []
    plot_list = []
    country = "India"
    chart_type = "cases"
    base_site = f'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/{country}?lastdays=all'
    r = requests.get(base_site)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        packages_json = r.json()

        today_date = str(date.today().strftime('%m{}%d{}%y').format('/','/'))
        if int(today_date[0:2])<10 and int(today_date[3:5])<10:
            today_date = today_date[1:]
            today_date = today_date[0 : 2 : ] + today_date[3 : :]
        elif int(today_date[0:2])<10:
            today_date = today_date[1:]
        elif int(today_date[3:5])<10:
            today_date = today_date[0 : 2 : ] + "/" + today_date[4 : :]

        for i in range(1,1000):
            current_date = DateFormatter(i)
            if current_date==today_date:
                f_date = datetime(2020, 1, 22)
                delta = given_date - f_date
                break;

        for i in range(delta.days):#Day 157 is 26th June
            try:
                a = DateFormatter(i)
                packages_str = json.dumps(packages_json['timeline'][chart_type][a], indent=2)
                finallist.append(int(packages_str))
            except KeyError:
                pass

        count = 0
        for i in finallist:
            count = count + 1
        for i in range(1,count+1):
            l2.append(i)
        for i in l2:
            plot_list.append(DateFormatterForPlot(i))

    else:
        print("Not a valid country")

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(y=finallist, x=l2, desc=plot_list))

    TOOLTIPS = """
    <style>
        .bk-tooltip>div:not(:first-child) {display:none;}
    </style>

    <b>X: </b> @desc <br>
    <b>Y: </b> @y{0,0}
    """

    plot = figure(background_fill_color='#fafafa', x_axis_label='Days', y_axis_label='Coronavirus {}'.format(chart_type.capitalize()), plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, toolbar_location=None)
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, legend = 'Number of {}'.format(chart_type.capitalize()), line_width=2, color='gray')
    cr = plot.circle('x', 'y', size=10, source=source, fill_color="grey", hover_fill_color="gainsboro", fill_alpha=0.1, line_color=None, hover_line_color="white", hover_fill_alpha=1)

    plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS, renderers=[cr]))
    plot.add_layout(Title(text="Coronavirus {} Example Graph".format(chart_type.capitalize()), align="center"), "above")
    plot.legend.location = 'top_left'
    plot.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False #Used to disable scientific notation on y-axis
```

The problem that is arising here is that more than one circle glyphs are being shown when cursor is hovered on the area of the plot where the density of circle glyphs are high.
I think there is a CustomJS callback for Hovertool to allow only one circle glyph to be shown on hovering mouse over it but I am not able to implement it.

Output of the snippet can be seen here http://geetanshjindal.pythonanywhere.com/charts/
I am using the latest bokeh version 2.1.1 and python version 3.6

Comment: It looks like the issue might be with your underlying data. Can you please share an extract for, say, June 26?

Comment: @gherka I have updated the snippet in question  and  the url http://geetanshjindal.pythonanywhere.com/charts/ to include the underlying data

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to include imports in your sample code as this will make it easier to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three options and all have to do with de-densifying your plot:

- Reduce the size of the circle glyphs so that they don't overlap. `size=5` seems to work OK for your plot width.
- Increase plot width so that the circle glyphs are more spaced out. Of course, this will add a scroll bar so might not be the best user experience.
- Don't remove the Bokeh toolbar and encourage the user to interact with the plot - zooming in to see all circle glyphs.

The approach of selectively showing tooltips using CSS is interesting, but it hides the decision-making ("show the tooltip only for the first circle of the overlapping two") from the user, potentially causing confusion.

One alternative approach would be to remove the tooltips altogether and add annotations in key places instead (passing a million of cases?), as well as putting a table with all dates and values as a side panel for reference.

For [annotations](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels), you can use a combination of a Label and [Bezier](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/bezier.html) curve models:

```
from bokeh.models import Label, Bezier

test_label = Label(x=50, y=550000, x_units='data', y_units='data',
                 text='Custom description of the datapoint', render_mode='css',
                 border_line_color='white', border_line_alpha=1.0,
                 border_line_width=3, background_fill_color='white',
                 background_fill_alpha=1.0)

# play around with control point values for best effect
curve_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x0=[150],
    y0=[395048],
    x1=[130],
    y1=[600000],
    cx0=[150],
    cy0=[500000],
    cx1=[150],
    cy1=[600000]       
    )
)

test_curve = Bezier(
    x0="x0", y0="y0", x1="x1", y1="y1",
    cx0="cx0", cy0="cy0", cx1="cx1", cy1="cy1",
    line_color="green", line_width=1)

plot.add_glyph(curve_source, test_curve)
plot.add_layout(test_label)
```

[image]